# Balanced vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

If $n$ vectors $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_n$ are given in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all lengths at most $1$, then it is not to hard to see that we can put $+$ and $-$ in place of $*$ in the expression
$$a_1 * a_2 * \cdots * a_n$$
so that the result will have length at most $\sqrt{n}$.

To see this, it's enough to choose $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$ independently and uniformly from $\{\pm 1\}$. Then, put $X={|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\lambda_i|}^2$. By a simple calculation, you will find that $E(X)=n$. Hence there exist specific $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n = \pm 1$ with and with $X\leq n$. Taking 
square roots gives the theorem.

Now I am curious to know, is it possible to generalize this theorem as follows?

Assume $N>n$ vectors $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_N$ are given in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all lengths at most $1$. Is it possible to put $+$ and $-$ in place of $*$ in the expression
$$a_1 * a_2 * \cdots * a_N ,$$
so that the result will have length at most $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a classical result of [Barany and Grinberg](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581900859) (generalizing an earlier result of Spencer) that there exist $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_N\in\{\pm 1\}$ with
  $$ \|\lambda_1a_1+\dotsb+\lambda_Na_N\| \le 2n. $$
The paper of Barany-Grinberg was published in 1981, but they indicated that the problem was posed in 1963 by Dvoretzky. Interestingly, Barany and Grinberg, along with Gergely Ambrus, have just published [another paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04027) on this subject.

Notice that for $n=2$, it is easy to get the sharp bound
  $$ \|\lambda_1a_1+\dotsb+\lambda_Na_N\| \le \sqrt 2; $$
it follows by using induction and observing that among any three vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ of length at most $1$, there are two vectors such that either their sum, or their difference has length at most $1$, and that for any two vectors of length at most $1$, either their sum, or their difference has length at most $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Is there any counterexample for the bound $\sqrt{n}$ for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: I don't know, but - have you checked the recent paper by Barany and Grinberg linked in my answer above?

Comment: I just saw the result. Unfortunately I have not found an appropriate time to read it yet :-(  but I am going to read it very soon. I will write here about it, if I find any other interesting things more than your comments.

Answer (score 2):

A nice and short proof of this statement is found the  1981 note of Spencer:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316581900339

He writes that the result had been known before the publication, although with no explicit reference. His proof is elegant, using the result for $n$ vectors, and then applying a probabilistic technique.